# Many to Many Relationship - AccountContact Relationship

Tags: accountcontactrelation

[image]

I have enabled Account Contact Relationship to use a "many to many" relationship which is working. But, getting an error "This contact already has a relationship with this account." when I try to add a contact through an account relationship with a new Role. Is there any way to avoid this error declaratively?

Comment: Please do not add tags that have nothing to do with your question, just because they have Salesforce in the tag name. This is the **Salesforce** Stack exchange, we know questions asked here are about Salesforce and you don't need to use tags to indicate that. The tag `[salesforce-dx]`, for example, is about the DX feature on this platform, which this question clearly is not.

Answer (score 0):

The contact can only have one relationship to a certain account.
U can use the relationship to connect a contact to multiple accounts.

Comment: Hello @RRI, Thanks for responding, I am aware that the Contact can have one relationship to One Account. I want to know if there is a way to achieve this(Able to add a Same Contact twice with a different Role/Positon) declaratively.